# AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator not working

Tags: iphone, json, swift, alamofire, activity-indicator

I have integrated `Alamofire`,`SwiftyJson` and `AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator` frameworks via pod in my project. The AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator is not showing up after following the instructions given in their Github page. 
https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator

It says all that is required for the activity indicator to work is the following line of code:

```
NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.shared.isEnabled = true
```

I basically just need a activity indicator to show whenever a request is being made or data is loading(Alamofire methods)

Comment: Where do you expect it to show in middle of screen?

Comment: Yes. Similar to UIActivityIndicatorview. I just need a loader to show whenever data is loading.

Answer (score 4):

You have actually misunderstood `AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator` is not actually a `UIActivityIndicator` like `MBProgressHUD` or `SVProgressHUD`. It will show a spinner in the status bar when an API call is there.

This will use to show `NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.shared.isEnabled = true` and `false` will hide from the status bar.

```
//Using MBProgressHUD
//Show indicator 
MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, parameters: parameter, encoding: .JSON)
 .responseJSON { response in
 //Hide indicator
MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: OMG...never noticed that. Thankyou so much. Anyways do you have any idea how to initiate a ActivityIndicator like MBProgressHUD or SVProgressHUD for alamofire?

Comment: @SachitPhilip Updated Answer

Comment: @SachitPhilip You can accept the answer if works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Parth the NetworkActivityIndicatorManager of almofire is not actually a UIActivityIndicator. For Activity Indicator you could use many of the third party available for toast message and instead on installing the cocoapod for all the files try the files to add manually this will not increase the size of your app as the cocoapods does during installation 
for Toast message you could use this : Toast message by  Charles Scalesse
1). Download the file and add the toast.swift file in your project 
2). to add toast you have to write self.maketoast

Comment: Got it. Thankyou :)

Comment: anytime bro. I think you are new here its fine take your time have a nice day